# Selecting elements outer container using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click an email sent from Twitch so I get the body of the email using this code:

```
chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Hey " + twitchUsername.ToLower() + ",')]")).click();
```

However, I get the error "Element not interactable" so I need to click the  tag which is surrounding it in HTML.

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/88a69160953f0e85156248fc3ed1e463

I'm not too familiar with XPath so I came here for help

Comment: Note, since it's Gmail the ID's change so I cannot use those as identifiers

Answer (score 0):

you should be using this xpath.

```
chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='afn'][contains(text(), 'Hey " + twitchUsername.ToLower() + ",')]")).click();
```